# Find boundary coordinates of a set of mesh points

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

I have a set of bmesh `verts` created like:

```
import bmesh
# ...
bm = bmesh.new()
# ...
bm.verts.new(...)
```

I intend to have all the points on the boundary of the `verts`. I can compute the boundary points by doing something like:

```
minX = min([co[0] for co in coords])
maxX = max([co[0] for co in coords])
minY = min([co[1] for co in coords])
maxY = max([co[1] for co in coords])
minZ = min([co[2] for co in coords])
maxZ = max([co[2] for co in coords])
print(minX, maxX, minY, maxY, minZ, maxZ)
```

However, I'm curious if there is any tool to get the min/max of bmesh `verts`, or even better, a tool to get the boundary points of bmesh `verts`. Thanks.

---

There is a [BMesh API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMVert.is_boundary), but not sure how to use it:

```
is_boundary
True when this vertex is connected to boundary edges (read-only).

Type:   boolean
```

Comment: If an edge is only used  for  one face then  it `is_boundary` and so are both of its vertices. The cube has no boundary edges the plane 4.

Comment: While not bmesh, the [`region_to_loop`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.region_to_loop) operator will select the boundary loop of the current selection. You would think this would be available in bmesh.